# AF-XDP support in the driver and testing it

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, driver, xdp-bpf

I'm trying to implement AF-XDP support in my driver using the 'igc' code as a reference. I want to add stubs first for e.g. ndo_xsk_wakeup and just see how the code flows etc and build it one at a time, i.e from configuration/setup to slowly enabling the actual data path.
The problem is I'm not able to figure out a suitable, quick n easy way to test this. I looked online and this tutorial talks about `xdpsock' in samples/bpf, but I could not find this in my kernel (linux-6.0.9) ? I see the xdp-tutorial, but i'm not sure of how to build and use that either
Any pointers or help in this regard would be highly appreciated, thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your linux distribution is configured i guess.. On a setup, when i ran make M=samples/bpf from my linux source directory i could see xdpsock binary generated and using that was able to get it running on my interface. But this was linux-5.19.8. Not seen in latest kernels starting from 6.0..Not sure why or how to use it now